# PSPICE ERROR(ORPSIM-15143): Voltage source and/or inductor loop involving

Tags: ac, dc, pspice, zvs

I'm facing a problem with an error message in Pspice. How do I address it?

```
nestlist:
X_M2         N02924 N02954 0 IRFP250
R_R3         N02954 0  10k TC=0,0 
V_V1         N02840 0 24Vdc
D_D2         0 N02954 D1N4742 
R_R1         N02840 N02881  470 TC=0,0 
R_R4         N02840 N02954  470 TC=0,0 
D_D1         0 N02881 D1N4742 
R_R2         0 N02881  10k TC=0,0 
D_D3         N02881 N02924 D1N3883 
C_C2         N02924 N02858  0.3uF  TC=0,0 
C_C3         N02924 N02858  0.3uF  TC=0,0 
X_M1         N02858 N02881 0 IRFP250
D_D4         N02954 N02858 D1N3883 
X_U2         0 N05630 N05496 N05645 684_1
C_C4         0 N05496  20n  TC=0,0 
C_C5         0 N05496  20n  TC=0,0 
C_C6         N05645 N05630  220u  TC=0,0 
Kn_K2         L_L2 L_L1     1
L_L1         N02840 N02858  91uH  
L_L2         N02840 N02858  91uH  

**** RESUMING kjkg.cir ****
.END

ERROR(ORPSIM-15143): Voltage source and/or inductor loop involving L_L2. You may break the loop by adding a series resistance
```

[image: Schematic]

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward.  Add resistors in line with each inductor to represent the inductor's ESR.  If you don't know what it is, 1mohm is a good starting point to at least get the simulation running.  If you have a specific part number you're using, get this value from the datasheet.

Answer (score 2):

Please see this page for information about SPICE:

[SPICE Information](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/reference/chpt-7/spice-quirks/)

In there is a discussion about inductor loops:

[image: Inductor looops]

You have just this construct in your netlist (L1 and L2) and for no reason that I can discern.  You can combine your two parallel inductors into a single inductor with 1/2 the L value and this problem will be resolved.